# Is there a way for two network nodes to connect with each other hiding in their NAT router?

Tags: networking, network-programming, router, nat, portforwarding

Mobile internet such as what I'm using is a strict NAT and does not allow you to edit the router settings for you to port forward. Given two mobile internet which I wish to connect with each other using socket. Both are hiding behind the ISP's strict NAT. Is there a way to connect them like connecting to a web domain which in turn a php script creates a route for them? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Internet mobility is different but if you want to implement something like connecting two devices which are behind NAT, thats possible. In NAT, only inside out connections are allowed. So you need a service in cloud which will keep record of the source IP and Source port of the connection initiated from the devices behind a NAT router. This service should act as a TCP level bridge and copy the TCP payload from one TCP connection to another.
Basically what we are trying to do is to trick the application behind the NAT thinking that its talking to a service in cloud, but instead actually it is talking to another device which probably is also behind NAT.